# ResolveUrl inserts extra quote

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis

I'm writing my first MVC2 app.  I've got my master page working beautifully, and when I run it locally it functions exactly like I want it to.

My problem is that I'm deploying it on a server that has a whole bunch of Applications.  ResolveUrl seems to be misbehaving.  I get the correct path, but for whatever reason something is inserting an extra quote, or dropping the quotes I have.

Here's my `<link>`:

```
<link href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Site.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

What comes out (client side, after ASP.NET is through with it):

```
<link href=/vcdemo/PhotoManager/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Obviously it's not what I want.  When I correct the quotes in Firebug the site displays correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try escaping (`\"`) the double quotes?

Comment: where? the <%= -> should be doing that for me, right?

Comment: I'm not rightly sure, that's why I asked. Inline scripting is something I try to keep away from in ASP.NET, and when I do I invariably have troubles similarly as trivial but tedious as this - can't really speak for how things are done in the MVC garden.

Comment: The concept of MVC is a complete paradigm shift. You're moving back to stateless web, so running controls like in WebForms is completely different. Inline scripting in MVC works much better than in Forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `Url.Content` helper:

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Also as it seems that you are using the WebForms view engine make sure you have removed any `runat="server"` attributes that might be present on the `<head>` tag.

`ResolveUrl` and `runat="server"` are legacy stuff and should not be used in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: ya beat me buy a few seconds. :( haha

Comment: Ok. That makes sense.  Why remove the runat=server ?

Comment: @Cpfohl, because `runat="server"` is used with server side controls. Server side controls no longer should be used in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Yup, you should never ever have to use a server side control in MVC. In fact, I took the "toolbox" right out of my IDE.

Comment: do I need it for anything at all, or can I do a solution wide find-replace 'runat="server"' with ''?

Comment: no you can't do that. a find/replace can break controls that require `runat`. Example `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ... />` would actually be replaced to `<input ... />`

Answer (score 2):

Since you say this is MVC, you should try and use a helper

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```